# Input type="file" showing weird behavior when used along with another input type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, input-type-file

I have an input `type="file"` and an `input type="text"`. When I choose the file first and then put text in the input box and click the Add button, the picture doesn't show but when I put the text first and then choose the picture (file), it behaves normally.I think there's some problem in the inputKey That I have given. Here's a link from where I found this method 
http://robhoffmann.me/2016/03/12/Clearing-a-file-input-in-React/

What I am trying to do: I want to be able to choose an Image and type a product name which will then show on the screen. As soon as I click the Add button. I want both the inputs i.e. file type and text type to reset so that I can add the picture and Name of next product and so on..

```
function Admin(props){

    const [productName, setproductName] = React.useState("");

    let [productPicture, setproductPicture] = React.useState({file:null,inputKey:Date.now()});


    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/">Go back</Link><br/><br/>
            <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>(productPicture=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))} key={productPicture.inputKey}></input><br/>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Product Name" onChange={(e)=>setproductName(e.target.value)} value={productName}></input><br/><br/>

<button type="Submit" onClick={(e)=>{props.AddInfo({productName,productPicture});setproductName("");setproductPicture({file:null,inputKey:Date.now()})}}>Add</button>
            <br/><br/>

            <div>
             {props.products.map((x)=>(<div>{x.name} {typeof x.picture === 'string' ? <img src={x.picture} alt="Product Picture" style={{width:"250px"}}></img>:""} </div>))}   
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin;
```

I expect the output to show the productName and productPicture when I click Add button but this only happens when I type in the text first and then choose the image/file and NOT when I do the vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this,

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e)=>(productPicture=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))} key={productPicture.inputKey}></input><br/>
```

You are directly trying to mutate the state, `productPicture=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])` which is wrong. Here you are not setting state. To set actual state you need to make use of `setproductPicture` `setter` function.

```
<input type="file" onChange={setImage} key={productPicture.inputKey} />
```

And `setImage` function should be,

```
const setImage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
  let file = e.target.files[0];  //Capture the file in variable otherwise event gets nullified and you won't get file.
  setproductPicture(prevState=>({
     ...prevState,
     file: URL.createObjectURL(file)
  }))
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fzmstk)

**Note:** `input` is an empty tag, don't close it like `<input></input>`. You can just do this, `<input />`.

Comment: Thank you so much.It works flawlessly and solved my problem.Can you please explain a bit more about what was wrong with my approach? And how is your approach different than mine??What exactly did you mean by 'mutating the state' ?

Comment: It means you are trying to do this `productPicture=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])` this is mutation (directly assigning value to state variable without using setter function).

Comment: In your case setter function is `setproductPicture`. So you should always change your state variable using this function.

Comment: To change one of the value from state object like we only want to change `file` value from `{file:null,inputKey:Date.now()}` we need to use `previous state` values as I did.

Comment: Read more obout setState here- https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60

Comment: Thanks a lot. Kinda new to react haha. Just one question, if i did onChange={(e)=>setproductPicture({file:URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])})} would it do not work the way it is supposed to?

Comment: As in the setImage function, we are setting file: URL.createObjectURL(file). So if we do it directly inside the onChange, how's it different?

Comment: If you do this, your state will change from `{file:null,inputKey:Date.now()}` to `{file:null}` and you will loose `inputKey`.

Comment: Got it. Pretty simple and straightforward explanation :)